# jGrasp can't find jar file even though it's in the classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath, jgrasp

OK.  At the risk of my reputation, I've read and followed all the advice about adding a jar file to the classpath in jGrasp.  The jmatio.jar file exists on my pc at

```
C:\Users\blevy\MCR\projects\code base\java\jmatio\lib\jmatio.jar
```

and it appears in the workspace and project classpaths correctly, but compilation gives...

```
driverFile.java:4: error: package jmatio.io does not exist
```

I note from:

```
http://intra.csb.ethz.ch/javadoc/metabolic/com/jmatio/io/MatFileReader.html
```

that jmatio derives from java.Lang.Object as com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.  Do I need to import the library as com.jmatio?  So simple?

Answer (score 0):

Well, duh.  It's import com.jmatio.io.MatFileReader.  Sorry for the bother.